# Nvidia device error in tensorflow

Tags: cuda, tensorflow

To test my tensorflow installation I am using the mnist example provided in tensorflow repository, but when I execute the convolutional.py script I have this output:

```
    I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
Extracting data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.2405
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 5.93GiB
Free memory: 5.83GiB
W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:590] creating context when one is currently active; existing: 0x29020c0
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:137] Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 1: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convolutional.py", line 339, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "convolutional.py", line 284, in main
    with tf.Session() as sess:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1187, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 552, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewDeprecatedSession(opts, status)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 24, in __exit__
    self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

My first idea was that maybe I had problems in cuda installation but I tested using one of the examples provided for nvidia. In this case I used this example:

> NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/6_Advanced/c++11_cuda

And the output is this:

```
GPU Device 0: "GeForce GTX 980 Ti" with compute capability 5.2

Read 3223503 byte corpus from ./warandpeace.txt
counted 107310 instances of 'x', 'y', 'z', or 'w' in "./warandpeace.txt"
```

Then my conclusion is the cuda is installed correctly. But I don not have any idea what is happening here. If someone can help me I will appreciated.

For more information this is my gpu configuration:

```
Tue Jan 31 19:42:10 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.57                 Driver Version: 367.57                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 560 Ti  Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 25%   45C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    463MiB /   958MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 980 Ti  Off  | 0000:03:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   31C    P8    13W / 280W |      1MiB /  6077MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

It is normal the two nvidia cards have the same physical id?

```
sudo lshw -C "display"
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM200 [GeForce GTX 980 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:50 memory:f9000000-f9ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:fa000000-fa07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:f6000000-f7ffffff memory:c8000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d3ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f8000000-f807ffff
```

Comment: to answer your edit, they dont have the same physical id

Comment: but, in the two cases has  physical id:0. Then they have the same physical id or not?

Comment: the pci buses are different. your edit is ompletely irrelevent

Comment: yes the buses are different but the physical id is not different and if I'm not wrong the physical id is used to select which gpu you want to use.

Comment: you are wrong. enumeration of devices in cuda doesnt rely on the pci id.

Comment: oh thanks, then I don't know what is happening. I recompiled the tensorflow manually and the same error is appearing.

Comment: If you read the error carefully, you will notice that the device which is failing is the second GPU which is your display device. If you make it compute restricted or use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES, the problem will penaltytake disappear

Comment: Thanks, using the cuda visible devices it is working. But my question is why is detecting my secong gpu how a possible candidate to use cuda?

Comment: Because it is a CUDA capable GPU and Tensorflow is designed to try and use all available GPUS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important points in the output you have shown is this:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 980 Ti
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.2405
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 5.93GiB
Free memory: 5.83GiB
```

i.e. the compute device you want is enumerated as device 0 and

```
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:137] Internal: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 1: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_DEVICE
```

i.e. the compute device generating the error is enumerated as device 1. Device 1 is your display GPU, which can't be used for computation in Tensorflow. If you either mark that device as compute prohibited with `nvidia-smi`, or use the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable to only make your compute device visible to CUDA, the error should probably disappear.

Comment: The solution using cuda visible devices is working but the solution using de nvidia-smi in my case is not working. I am using this command: sudo nvidia-smi -i $GPU_ID --compute-mode=PROHIBITED but tensorflow it is still trying to use the display gpu. But the other solution is working well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error when I attempted to run the `classify_image.py` script that is part of [the image recognition tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition).  Since I already had a running Python session (elpy) in which I had run some TensorFlow code, the GPUs were allocated there and thus were not available for the script I was attempting to run from shell.

Quitting the existing Python session resolved the error.